# Sharepoint 2007, rendering menu as ul

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Is there a way to render the ugly  sharepoint2007 menu as ul and li instead of table ?

Comment: I have never created such a customization so I can only suggest that you should read about the custom navigation providers ([SPNavigationProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigationprovider%28v=office.12%29.aspx)).